next.js version 14.2.1 build size is too high
its my first next.js project using app router.
my project's build size is too high, 290 mb, the files mainly responsible for this is
.next\cache\webpack\client-production\0.pack which is 130 mb and
.next\cache\webpack\server-production\0.pack which is 115 mb
while my whole app size in root folder is 2.28mb and my public folder size is 2.53mb and my node modules folder size is 555mb
i completely installed new next.js project, and without modifying any files i create a build just to check its size, and the build was of 29mb, but on google every where every one recommended that the build size should not be more than 1 mb
